# Django REST Framework: preventing access to objects you don't own

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `ModelViewSet` and `ModelSerializer` `Foo`. The `get_queryset` method in the `ViewSet` filters the results by the user (i.e. users should only see `Foo` objects they own when they `GET` from `foo/`). I'm trying to understand how DRF prevents users from accessing objects you don't want them to access or modify particular objects by their id (as in `foo/123/`).

In the `foo/123/` case, I noticed that `get_queryset` also gets called on the `GET`. So are results being first culled by `get_queryset` before an individual object is retrieved? I didn't assume that and instead  defined custom permissions and overwritten `has_object_permission` for every single object in my api, assuming that's the way to prevent access and manipulation of objects that a user is not authorized to. But can I just rely on the filtering I have in `get_queryset` to ensure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tl;DR: Yes.

`get_object` will call `get_object_or_404` on the QuerySet returned by `get_queryset` — so you're good.

Comment: Thanks! Is this mentioned in the docs or discovered through inspecting the source?